# Pad both sides of 1D array while keeping edge indices

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 1D array `x` of size `n` and some index `i` where `0 <= x <= len(arr)`, I would like to be able to extract `x[i]` along with `l` neighboring elements to the left and `l` neighboring elements to the right, like this:

```
>>> i = 5
>>> l = 2
>>> x = np.arange(9,)
>>> def crop_array(arr):
    '''do something'''

>>> crop_array(x)
array([2,3,4,5,6])
```

The thing is, I would like to keep all of these arrays the same size, so if `i = 1 - l < 0`, then I want to pad the array to yield something like `array([0,1,2,3,4])`. The would also hold true in cases where `i + l > len(x)`, except the padding would be on the other side.

I'm trying to pad both sides of the array and then slice it:

```
def crop_array(arr, l, i):
    x = np.zeroes(len(arr) + 2 * l)
    x[l:len(x)-l] = arr
```

but I'm not sure how I can make it so that I can reindex the array to get the elements I want.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, figured it out. I can just add l to i.